# How to extract address with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a document where there's an address, but at the beginning there's a date. I want a regex to extract the address because I'm getting just the date.

The format of the address

- 1 to 5 numbers then
- space then
- consecutive words but no digits then
- space or comma then
- word then
- space or comma then
- 2 uppercase letters (finish at these two letters)

i.e.

- 5664 rue pierre labelle montreal QC
- 5456 avenue martin curé, sherbrooke, QC

I tried this but I get nothing. I played more than a couple of hours, but I get sometimes the date of the document which is before the address and then 2 words at the beginning of the paragraph.

```
  "\\d{1,5}\\s(\\b\\w+\\b){1,2}\\w*\\s?,?\\w*\\s?,?\\w*\\s?,?[A-ZA-Z]"
```

This is part of the text

> 23 July 2016
>
> George Washington living at 5664 rue pierre labelle montreal QC G1H
>   3A4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Another document

> 05 January 2016
>
> Juana Perez living at 5456 avenue martin curé, sherbrooke, QC, 
>   G1H 3A8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Another document

```
Salvador Dali living at

5 Ch Ste-Catherine 
Montreal QC 
J2S 8W3
```

Comment: This might get a bit messy because each address appears to have its own unique format.  May we ask whence is the source for these addresses, and might there be a way for you to export them with them all having the same format?

Comment: We are in a process to uniform this data and suggest a change to our suppliers. But in the meantime, all texts come from contracts provided by different suppliers. We generate the file locally (and saved in db) through a service, but the text is sent by them. We've identified 3 patterns which I provided in my examples. There are many contracts but these are the 3 format of addresses.

Comment: I gave you a solution below.  I think you don't actually need to use regular expressions here.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : https://regex101.com/r/vA8oC2/2

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my question and I added an example of the format of the document. I doesn't work when it's in this text. I wanna extract from the number to the province code.

Comment: May be this will help: https://regex101.com/r/vA8oC2/4

Comment: Yes, it did. I was playing with your previous pattern and I got from the year till the zip code, but I didn't realized the 'at'. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus : You are welcome. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is java equivalent of [regex101.com/r/vA8oC2/4](http://regex101.com/r/vA8oC2/4).

Basically start searching @ `"at"` till you find `"."`

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegex {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("at\\s(\\d{1,5}[\\s\\w,\\d]+)\\.",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE| Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    String s ="23 July 2016\n"
            + "George Washington living at 5664 rue pierre labelle montreal QC G1H 3A4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"
            +"05 January 2016\n"
            + "Juana Perez living at 5456 avenue martin curé, sherbrooke, QC, G1H 3A8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    System.out.println("Searching Addresses.....");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(s);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    System.out.println("Completed Searching Addresses");


 }
}
```

Comment: Another question for you. I another example where the address is at the signature. There is still at but then new line and each segment of the address in a new line. I want to try to fit [\r\n]+ in your pattern but it doesn't  work. I updated the question with the 3rd variant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One really nice thing about this data set is that the three address types each has a different number of lines, specifically 1, 2, or 3.  You can use this to determine which format an address has and then easily extract what you need.  You will notice that I did not use even one regular expression in my solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int state = 0;

    String line;
    String[] array = new String[3];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("addresses.txt"));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("")) {
            processAddress(array, state);
            state = 0;
        }
        else {
            array[state] = line;
            ++state;
        }
    }
}

// You are free to handle each extracted address component however you like.
// For the purpose of illustration, I chose to print the components to
// the console.
public static void processAddress(String[] array, int state) {
    switch(state) {
        case 1:
            // 1701 Verling Ave, Saanichton, BC, V8M 1X6
            String[] parts = array[0].split(",");
            System.out.println("Address is " + parts[0]);
            System.out.println("State/city is " + parts[1] + ", " + parts[2]);
            System.out.println("Zip code is " + parts[3]);

        case 2:
            // 2916 Prior St
            // Victoria BC V8T3Y5
            String[] parts = array[1].split(" ");
            System.out.println("Address is " + array[0]);
            System.out.println("State/city is " + parts[0] + ", " + parts[1]);
            System.out.println("Zip code is " + parts[2]);

        case 3:
            // 834 Johnson St
            // Victoria BC
            // V8W 1N3
            System.out.println("Address is " + array[0]);
            System.out.println("State/city is " + array[1]);
            System.out.println("Zip code is " + array[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have one problem, my files are not only addresses. The text is the actual contract where somewhere in the text is the address as in the examples. That's what I though that using regular expression would be quick to match a pattern an extract the data that I need.

Comment: Then you asked a bad question IMO.  You need to tell us the _exact_ format of the addresses and you did not do this.